# Field Modified shows date, but no time

Tags: column, date-time, modified

In a view of a document library I have the field "Modified" and this is showing only dates but no time. I would like to display the time aswell.

From my understanding it is ill advised to alter this field OOTB, but rather to create a calculated field and format it the way I want.

I have checked the column properties for this Modified-field, and it is set to "Date and time", which is why I find it curious that it only displays the date. In any case I have created another (calculated) field which I am attempting to format the way I want, but with not luck.

Under the Formula section of this new calculated field I am attempting to format "Modified" like this:

```
=TEXT([Modified],"dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm")
```

I want the result to appear like this 14.10.2014 15:59. However, when trying to save the above formula I get the "Sorry, something went wrong" page and the mention that the syntax is probably wrong. I am unable to see any obvious errors with the syntax and have tried a multitude of approaches - like removing the "", removing [] from modified and so forth.

I need the field to display time aswell and I am not sure if this is the best approach either. Anyone got any tips to how I could do this? Perhaps the calculated field approach isn't the best either?

Comment: Are you using SharePoint 2013?  If so, have you tried switching the `Modified` column on your list from `Friendly` Display Format to `Standard`?

Comment: I am using Sharepoint 2013, and changing from friendly format to standard in itself does nothing but change the format from "15 nov" to "15.10.2014". However, I noticed that the time format under regional settings was set to 12 hour. Changing to standard format AND time format to 24 hours yields the result I wanted. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The point is that formula expression is usually language dependent.

For example, is site locate is set to `1033 (English - United States)`, then the formula you have provided in the question is absolutely correct:

Syntax: `TEXT(value,format_text)`  [Source](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/TEXT-function-4b46e545-e612-4c84-ac23-edfa68007945?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

But let's say the site locate is set to `1049 (Russia)`, in that case the proper syntax would be:

```
ТЕКСТ(значение;формат)
```

What matters here is delimiter, as you can see it is `;` for 1049 locale  and **not** `,` like in case of 1033 locale.

**Solution**

1. Identify the locate of SharePoint site (go to `Regional Settings` - see the figure 1)
2. Go to [A list of available functions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointtechnology/CH011711171033.aspx) and verify the proper
   syntax for a function according to the language specified (see figure 2 and 3)

Figure 1. How to identify Locale settings
[image]

Figure 2. TEXT formula for 1049 locale (e.g. 1049 locale)
[image]

Figure 3 How to determine formula syntax

[image]

**Update**

How to set Time Format 
[image]

### References

- [Overview of formulas and functions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointtechnology/CH011711541033.aspx)
- [A list of available functions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointtechnology/CH011711171033.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for this well explained post, it definitely pointed me in the right direction. I might not need the calculated field after all. I changed the field to show standard format instead of friendly format. Also (thanks to you) I looked into the regional settings and noticed that for the site it was set to 12-hour format. Changed this to 24-hour and the field now shows as I want it to. I was wondering though, creating new sites and subsites the standard is still 12-hour even if I change it on the root site collection. Do you know of any way to change default to 24-hour and standard-mode?

Comment: Yes, it is doable, by enabling "All sub-sites inherit these Regional Settings" will apply the changes, including Time format to all sub sites (see the updated answer)

Answer (score 0):

Check your Site Columns definition; when I look at a Modified column in a document library, I see date and time.

Either Site Column or Site Content Type (I believe Site Column is the driver), check your params.

```
Column Name: Date Modified (from Existing Core Document Columns) 
In additional column settings:    
     Date and Time Format: **Date and Time**
```

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2016 the Modified column can be updated to a Display Format of "Standard" instead of "Friendly" to show the time (and, if applicable, current year).

Comment: Please consider the comment from OP where they said changing it to "Standard" did n't work on its own and required also changing their regional settings.